# Why are monsters and the like in anime usually adorable girls?

Tags: anime-production, tropes

In many anime nowadays, the dragons, monsters, devil, semi-human or orcs are usually adorable girls maybe with thicc figures. Say, in *Dropkick on My Devil*, the devil from the hell is like an innocent little girl. In the *good old days*, things were different. The vampires in *Blood: The Last Vampire* are closer to what people would expect of a monster, but this kind of appearance of a monster seems quite rare today.

Why are monsters and the like in anime usually adorable girls nowadays?

- the devil from the hell in *Dropkick on My Devil*
  [image]
- a vampire in *Blood: The Last Vampire* (bottom right)
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

You are conflating different genres.

**2018, Goblin Slayer**
Goblin:

[image]

**1988, Kyuuketsuki Miyu**
Vampire:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some of this is due to the influence of Japanese folklore. Japan has many folk tales and urban legends regarding a spirit or monstrous creature that takes the form of an attractive young woman or a crying child in order to lure people in, which then turns into a hangered old woman with monstrous features, before either attacking the person or fleeing suddenly.

Think the ghost in the library from the original Ghostbusters.

Answer (score -3):

I think it continues the trend of [moe anthropomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moe_anthropomorphism), even into creating a new genre called "monster musume".

- answer of Aki Tanaka ♦